# Is it possible to input a command to the terminal through a txt or CSV file automatically instead of writing it out by hand?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

For example, writing in sudo cd codeFolder, then vi code.c all automatically synchronously. Instead of straight commands, I would like to input strings into the terminal that would be traced by my Linux program. [Example of what I am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vH35.png). Don't really worry about the command not found error, I would just like to parse the user input through another command that I am working with.

Comment: Type the commands in the .bashrc file in the home directory. bash would execute the commands at the start. Another option is to use the expect shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Wow, I wrote the original answer without realizing you wanted to use files. You can do it in c++ like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::ifstream fin(argv[1]);
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(fin, line))
        std::system(line);
}
```

Similar enough to the other example, but using files.

ORIGINAL:

A quick and easy (though potentially insecure) way to do it is to use the `system()` function provided in the `cstdlib.h` file.

Something like this:

```c
#include <cstdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    for(int i=0;i < argc; ++i)
        system(argv[i]);
}
```

This would be the usage:

```sh
$ executer "cd codeFolder" "vim code.c"
```

In this case, I believe it's fine to use it, since you'd be using it to execute commands yourself, but you have to keep in mind that it can allow anything to be executed if you don't properly sanitize the inputs, the arguments are also vulnerable to binary exploitation.

Alternatively, you can use Bash itself to execute the commands:

```sh
$ cd codeFolder; vim code.c
```

The semicolon is used to execute a command once the first one finishes executing, regardless of its return value, if you opt for this route, I recommend you do the following:

```sh
$ cd codeFolder && vim code.c
```

This will only execute `vim code.c` if `cd codeFolder` is successful. There's also an OR operator (`||`), that executes the command if the one before is not successful.